# Apple Automator / Scripting - Resize the same image to multiple sizes

Tags: shell, automation, applescript, automator

I have an image and would like to resize it to give different sizes. Currently, I have 5 different automator scripts and I choose each one on the image file right click -> quick actions.

Ideally, I'd have one automator that would size them all to the different sizes OR I'd be able to run all the 5 scripts with one click.

Can't seem to figure out how to do either... any help?

edit: Here is one automator workflow which resizes the input finder image to 64px wide. I want to resize an image to 512, 256, 128, 64, 32 all in one flow rather than having to do each one after the other.

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under **macOS Catalina** using **Automator** I created a *Quick Action* setting the *workflow* to, **Workflow receives current [image files] in [Finder]**, with the following *Actions*:

**Set Value of Variable**

- **Variable: [Selected Files]**

---

**Get Value of Variable**

- **Variable: [Selected Files]**
- **Options**

  - **[√] Ignore this actions input**

**Duplicate Finder Items**

**Rename Finder Items: Add Text**

- **[Add Text]**
- **Add: _x32 [after name]**

**Scale Images**

- **[To Size (pixels)]   32**

---

**Get Value of Variable**

- **Variable: [Selected Files]**
- **Options**

  - **[√] Ignore this actions input**

**Duplicate Finder Items**

**Rename Finder Items: Add Text**

- **[Add Text]**
- **Add: _x64 [after name]**

**Scale Images**

- **[To Size (pixels)]   64**

---

Now repeat this again from **Get Value of Variable** through **Scale Images** set of *actions*  three more times, changing the settings to 128, 256 and 512.

Then when you select **image files** in **Finder** and run the. e.g. **Scale Selected Image(s)**, *Service/Quick Action* it will create all the *files* in one *workflow*.

As you can see by first setting a *variable* to hold the *pathnames* of the *selected* **image files** then it can be retrieved any number of times to process through the set of *Actions*. You just have to check  **[√] Ignore this actions input** on each of the **Get Value of Variable** *actions* so its disconnected from the previous *action* so it's independent of the set of *actions* before it.

---

Note in the image below how there is a disconnect between whichever *action* is before the **Get Value of Variable** *action* as a result of checking **[√] Ignore this actions input**.

[image]